# Inno Setup Check if file exist in selected destination location

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have created files for a program I want to make as an update.
I would like it, before the installation, to check whether the program is also in the standard directory, and if not the one itself the right directory can choose where the program is.

I have tried this:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "C:\Data"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]
function NextButtonClick(PageId: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
    if (PageId = wpSelectDir) and not FileExists(ExpandConstant('C:\Program\Test\Test.exe')) then begin
        MsgBox('YourApp does not seem to be installed in that folder.  Please select the correct folder.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
        exit;
    end;
end;
```

But during the installation it does not check it.
Whether the program is available or not, it installs it anyway.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Your question is unclear, if you want to check if a file exists in the destination, use `FileExists` Function!

Comment: Ok for example: I have a program installed names "Abc1".
"Abc1" program directory "C:\program\Abc1" and there is the "Abc1.exe"
I create a txt "Abc1.txt" and with the Setup I would "install" the "Abc1.txt" into the Abc1 Directory because the Program is located there, if is not there i would like to have the option to search the right directory where is the Abc1.exe.

Comment: This is an example.
I hope now it is understandable

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `{app}` constant in the test to check the selected folder:

```pascal
FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\Test.exe'))
```